# How can I search for primary key in APEX Interactive grid search page field?

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I search by primary key value in APEX interactive grid ,

by default the search page can search all text columns only , but I need to search by primary key also for example ORDER_ID .

I checked the page and region attributes but I didn't find the way to change the query and search for primary key in the query .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add another column to the query.

It seems that the primary key column is a number. Apply `TO_CHAR` function to it and it'll appear as *text column* and will thus be searchable.

Something like this:

```
select empno,                          --> primary key
       to_char(empno) as text_empno,   --> TO_CHAR applied to the PK column
       ename
from emp
```

How does it look like?

[image]

Comment: thank you its working but there is no way to add number columns in interactive grid or dates why only text columns can search by ?

Comment: You're welcome. If there is a way to do what you ask, I don't know it, sorry.

Comment: in interactive report I can search for all columns type , I used it also